# sending a message from the administrator to the channel (Discord Bot)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

if the server administrator writes to the bot, then the bot will send this message to the channel?

the bot sends messages to the channel only from the server administrator, the administrator writes a private message to the bot…

i am newbie thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it very simple:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(administrator=True)
async def send_message(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, message: str):
    await channel.send(message)
```

To use this command type: `[your_prefix]send_message #channel your message`
**Note:** This command only works for members whose have `administrator` permissions.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there a detailed action?  I'm a newbie, and how can I record the administrator and the channel to which the message will be sent?

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Is it clear to you?

Comment: i get errors when i use it
https://ibb.co/NFBW10g

Comment: Write from `from discord.ext import command` at the beginning of file. Also replace `bot` with `client`. `[your_prefix]send_message #channel your message` is an example of usage you need to type it in a discord chat to trigger the command.

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong
https://ibb.co/K6knY2k

Comment: Remove `[your_prefix]send_message #channel your message` from your code.

Comment: it did not help, the error in the console remained

Comment: Try this code https://pastebin.com/HvJLbSHX

Comment: the error disappeared, but the bot does not send my message to the channel when I write to it

Comment: What did you write to a chat?

Comment: I wrote a normal text to the bot, but he did not send this text to the channel

Comment: Have you administrator permissions? Have the bot `send_messages` permissions in the target channel? How you use the command? You need to type in the chat for example `!send_message #channel test message` where `#channel` is your channel.

Comment: yes, I and the bot have administrator rights, but I do not need to send commands to the bots, but simple text, I write a message to the bot in private messages, and it sends my message to the channel on its own behalf

Comment: Ok, understandable. Then try something like https://pastebin.com/hjxv7y82. Pay attention to the comments on the code

Comment: thanks, it works!) but how to add an image?  if I send a picture, the bot does not send it

Comment: I have edited my code https://pastebin.com/vgWLiBad.

Comment: it shows one error
https://ibb.co/jZZ4t5F

Comment: Oh, use `message` instead of `ctx.message`.

Comment: it doesn't work, bot doesn't send image and text(

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: there is no error, but I do not understand what the problem is